# Trying to run UWP in release mode gives an "Payload contains two or more files.." error

Tags: xamarin.forms

I asked this on the Xamarin forums but got no response.

Running my app in debug mode works fine, but when I try to run in release mode, I get these errors:

Error Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'e_sqlite3.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\Bob.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v140\1.1.8\runtimes\win10-arm\native\e_sqlite3.dll
C:\Users\Bob.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v140\1.1.8\runtimes\win10-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll

I have seen other posts where some users have updated the nuget for UWP and others that have actually deleted one of the dll's, but none of these work for me; when I try to delete one of them, I then get an error that it is missing, so not sure what to do.

I have deleted my nuget folder and re-got everything fresh, cleaned my solution, rebooted, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up opening an issue with Microsoft over it and turns out that I had the build target set to ARM (Project properties->Build->Platform Target) which apparently tries to copy 2 different versions.  I set it to x86 and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the project was set to target x64 in the project properties, but when I debug, I debugged using x86. The moment I switched to debug using x64, it worked for me.