# UWP: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.uwp

Heyho,

I'm working my way through Xamarin.Forms right now and today I got the following error when I tried to Release compile the UWP project of my app (Debug is working):

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.dll'. Source files:
C:\Users\[...]\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.0-preview1-26926-04\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
C:\Users\[...]\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
```

The projects shared library compiles as netstandard2.0 and again includes a netstandard2.0 library itself, though I don't believe it should be a problem.

The UWP project references "Universal Windows" and the (self-compiled) [SQLite.Net](https://github.com/softlion/SQLite.Net-PCL) library. It also referenced the "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindows" NuGet package, but I uninstalled it (attempting to solve the issue above).
I also tried Cleaning and recompiling the solution, removing and restoring the actual NuGet directories, adding and removing references, up- and downgrading of the UWP packages, changing the build order of my solutions projects...but nothing worked.

Does anyone have any idea what I could do here? 
My main problem is that the error seems to come from .NET packages that I can't exchange/remove without crashing the whole project...

Comment: Have you tried `sqlite-net-pcl 1.5.166-beta`? Please check this link:https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/389#issuecomment-342318144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632031/trying-to-run-uwp-in-release-mode-gives-an-payload-contains-two-or-more-files) I found a solution to my problem.

Though it wasn't the build target under (Project properties->Build->Build Target) for me I noticed the checkbox "Compile with .NET Native toolchain". I removed the tick and the project compiles fine for Release.